# How to know when processes are over in python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

i am new to multi process development. I have to rename a lot of files (approximatively 70000)

so here is what i have done :

```
import os
import sys
import glob
from multiprocessing import Process

cst_id = sys.argv[1]
data=sys.argv[2]
main_path="/scality/hmo02/data/fdata/"+data+"/isei/"+cst_id+"/"

nb_process=100

def rename(file_lst):
    for f in file_lst:
        split_path=os.path.split(f)
        container_path=split_path[0]
        dir_to_rename=split_path[1]
        if(dir_to_rename.startswith('001_')):
            pass
        else:
            new_path=container_path+"/001_"+dir_to_rename
            os.rename(f,new_path)

def chunks(l, n): 
    return [l[x: x+n] for x in range(0, len(l), n)]

if(data=="odata"):
    id_data_file_lst=glob.glob(main_path+"*/*/*/*")
    chunked_lst=chunks(id_data_file_lst,nb_process)
    proc_lst=[]
    for lst in chunked_lst:
        proc=Process(target=rename, args=(lst))
        proc.start()
        proc_lst.append(proc)
    for p in proc_lst:
        p.join()
```

I have an other rename to do after this one but i have to be sure the first treatment is over to launch my other treatment. My question is : how to know if all processes are terminated ?
i am not sure of how i use `p.join()`

Comment: Have you read _"https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html"_? With `multiprocessing.Process.join` you can wait until the process has finished and with `multiprocessing.Process.is_alive` you can check if a process is still running. You can decorate your function `rename` with a callback function that is called after the function `rename` has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html. With `multiprocessing.Process.join` you can wait until the process has finished and with `multiprocessing.Process.is_alive` you can check if a process is still running. You can decorate your function `rename` with a callback function that is called after the function `rename` has finished.

Here is an example for the callback:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
from multiprocessing import Process

cst_id = sys.argv[1]
data=sys.argv[2]
main_path="/scality/hmo02/data/fdata/"+data+"/isei/"+cst_id+"/"

nb_process=100

def rename(file_lst):
    for f in file_lst:
        split_path=os.path.split(f)
        container_path=split_path[0]
        dir_to_rename=split_path[1]
        if(dir_to_rename.startswith('001_')):
            pass
        else:
            new_path=container_path+"/001_"+dir_to_rename
            os.rename(f,new_path)

def cb():
    print('Process has finished')

def wrapper(file_lst):
    rename(file_lst)
    cb()

def chunks(l, n): 
    return [l[x: x+n] for x in range(0, len(l), n)]

if(data=="odata"):
    id_data_file_lst=glob.glob(main_path+"*/*/*/*")
    chunked_lst=chunks(id_data_file_lst,nb_process)
    proc_lst=[]
    for lst in chunked_lst:
        proc=Process(target=wrapper, args=(lst))
        proc.start()
        proc_lst.append(proc)
    for p in proc_lst:
        p.join()
```

Comment: so instead of printing "process has finished" i could increment a global variable counter and test if the counter is equal to the number of sublist ? thanks for your answer i think it is the way to go